# How to reset etree using lxml

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

How do I "reset" an etree using LXML in Python 2.7?

I have one file that contains a list of files. For each of the files in this list I store the information in an element tree in LXML, then write the LXML to file. What I'd like to be able to do once I write to file is restore the etree to its initial state.

Conceptually this is where I'm at:

```
from lxml import etree

for file in list:
    quiz = etree.Element('quiz')
    open file and process contents:
        "add a bunch of stuff to etree"
        etree.SubElement(quiz,'stuff')
        "print etree to xml file"
        dataOut = etree.tostring(quiz, pretty_print = True)
        output_file.write(dataOut)
        "reset etree to blank file"
```

Comment: Would not you get a brand new `quiz` element on every iteration? Why do you need to reset the tree? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like it just "stacks" quizzes in the etree object, so when I write dataOut to file its not a concatenation of the previous iterations and the current. Like file 1 == 1kb, file 2 = 2kb, etc. and the contents are always the last plus the next.

Comment: Got it. Can you show where `etree` is coming from? Thanks.

Comment: edited the question to show where etree comes from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any issues with the following setup similar to the one you have:

```
from lxml import etree

for item in ["test1", "test2", "test3"]:
    quiz = etree.Element('quiz')

    etree.SubElement(quiz, 'stuff', attrib={"attr": item})
    print etree.tostring(quiz, pretty_print = True)
    print "---"
```

which prints:

```
<quiz>
  <stuff attr="test1"/>
</quiz>

---
<quiz>
  <stuff attr="test2"/>
</quiz>

---
<quiz>
  <stuff attr="test3"/>
</quiz>

---
```

I don't see quizzes stack which probably means the problem is somewhere else in your real code.

Comment: You're right. The problem was in my code. I was setting the Quiz element at the list level, not the document level.

Comment: In hindsight I should have just posted the code I had, but it's 100 lines so I thought it would be easier to just write what I'm trying to accomplish as opposed to what is causing the failure.]

Comment: @KurtisAS-K that's alright, it happens. What is important is that it's solved now.